# Xen DomU images running on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xen, centos6, ubuntu-12.04

I have backed up the contents of /etc/xen/ and /var/lib/xen and have installed Ubuntu 12.04 hoping to migrate off of CentOS.

I am attempting to test some of these images and am receiving some odd errors. Firstly after I startup vm-0 from an old configuration I see this:

```
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0 68654    24     r-----     28.3
vm-0                                         1  4096     1     --p---      0.0
```

The command used to start the domain was `xm create vm-0` which is what would have started the VM on CentOS. I also tried with the "xl" toolset but maybe that is something to migrate to after I get the older vm's working.

Bottom line, does it seem as though backing up the images from /var/lib/xen and /etc/xen for configurations on CentOS would work on Ubuntu or am I heading down a horrible path. My other option is to go back and reinstall CentOS and backup the images in another fashion.

Comment: I see nothing wong with your path. Did you try to open the console on that vm-0 and then unpause it `xm unpause vm-0`? Is this a HVM (Windows) DomU?

Comment: I actually was unable to migrate these in a timely fashion. I was using a CentOS based Dom0 and DomU. I now have migrated and set everything up on a Ubuntu 12.04 Dom0 and DomU.